# How to stop splitting single python log messages across multiple log entries in cloudwatch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, python-logging

In my python code I have something like this:

```py
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
try: 
    raise Exception("!")
except Exception as err:
    LOGGER.exception(f"Some context info")
```

Unfortunately over in cloudwatch, I see every line of the stack trace appearing as a separate log entry. I want that entire stack trace to show up as a single log entry in cloudwatch. How can I make that happen?

I don't think it matters, but in case it does, I'm on the python 3.7 lambda runtime.

Comment: You could use a JSON logging format like https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger or you could skip the logger & let Lambda handle the exception - which will also format the stack-trace as a single log entry

Answer (score 4):

A little hack with traceback module solves this issue.

```
import traceback

try:
    do_stuff_here()
except ClientError as e:
    tb = traceback.format_exc().replace("\n", "\r")
    logger.error("Error %s. Traceback: %s", e, tb)
```